# Mysql Sum group by with two tables sums two or more times(altered)

Tags: php, mysql

Spends a lot in query to bring the results. I received only the wrong answer.

### Ledger Table

particulars|cr|dr|tds|debit

P-01|500|0|50|50

P-02|1500|0|0|0

P-01|7500|0|0|0

Stationary|0|100|0|0

### Billing_details Table

bill_no|party_com_name|total_cost

BILL-01|P-01|2500

BILL-02|P-02|4000

BILL-03|P-01|9000

### Party Table

p_id|party_com_name

P-01|ABC

P-02|XYZ

### I want the output as

party_com_name|total_cost|paidamt|pendingamt

AA|11500|8000|3500

BB|4000|1500|2500

the formula for above result:

**total_cost**=sum of all total_cost from billing details with same name

**paidamt**=sum of cr+tds+debit from ledger with samename

**pendingamt**=total_cost-paidamt from the result

Please help

Comment: My Code:                                          select a.party_com_name,sum(a.total_cost) as total_cost,b.paidamt, (sum(a.total_cost)-b.paidamt) as pendingamt from 
(
 select distinct (b.party_com_name), (b.total_cost) as total_cost from billing_details b, ledger l where l.party_com_name=b.party_com_name
) a,
(
    select sum(l.cr) as paidamt from ledger l,billing_details b where l.party_com_name=b.party_com_name
) b

group by
a.party_com_name

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
Billing_details.party_com_name,
SUM(Billing_details.total_cost) AS total_cost,
SUM(Ledger.cr) AS paidamt,
(total_cost - paidamt) AS pendingamt 
FROM 
Billing_details
INNER JOIN Ledger
ON Ledger.bill_no = Billing_details.bill_no
GROUP BY Billing_details.party_com_name;
```

Comment: Thanks bro...It works.. Can you explain the code. I put ledger.party_com_name=Billing_details.party_com_name, it add two or more times. but when i use bill_no, it is fine..HOW???

Comment: It works with bill_no, because that is the primary key in one table and the foreign key in another and it is unique for each line, it is what should be used for a join. The party_com_name seemed like an initial good candidate for the join, but if it is not unique it may give strange results, like you described. Don't hesitate to accept the answer if it resolves your issue. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, the question is altered, and there is no bill_no in ledger, it only have party_com_name, now it gives strange results, and how to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

**Query:-**

```
SELECT billing_details.party_com_name,SUM(billing_details.`total_cost`) `total_cost`, SUM(ledger_table.`cr`) `paidamt` ,  ((SUM(billing_details.`total_cost`))-(SUM(ledger_table.`cr`))) as `pendingamt`
FROM billing_details
INNER JOIN ledger_table
ON
billing_details.bill_no = ledger_table.bill_no
GROUP BY billing_details.party_com_name
```

Comment: The result is wrong. it sums, three times the values(value *3),  the above query result is **AA|34500|24000|10500**....this is wrong output.,I want the output as above mentioned